# error with exit status 1 while installing spyder terminal

Tags: pip, anaconda, spyder

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z3vdlz4p\pywinpty\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z3vdlz4p\pywinpty\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z99eojcg\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pywinpty' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give us your code. Please edit your question to add your code so we can help you.

Comment: Post the command you have tried and the **full** error that you are getting. What you habve posted here is only the last part of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 32 bit version of python installed as your isntallation directory `python38-32` suggests. Looking at your error, it fails when trying to install `pywinpty`. A [quick look at github](https://github.com/spyder-ide/pywinpty/issues/130) shows that 32 bit is not supported by them. There is probably no reason for you to not have the 64 bit version of python, so simply remove the 32 bit version and install the 64 bit version. Then try again